# ASP.net dynamic menu loads slow with multiple sub menus

Tags: asp.net

We have a fairly large menu structure with dynamic menus and sub menus that we are trying to output to an unordered list or dropdown but if we show level 3 and below it takes forever to load the page. I am at a loss of how to speed this up. Any help would be greatly appreciated and forever in your debt :)

This is the menu menu_dropdown.ascx code

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" Inherits="BaseUserControl"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.sqlClient " %>

<script runat="server">
    Private sConn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SiteConnectionString").ConnectionString.ToString()
    Private oConn As New SqlConnection(sConn)
    Dim nCount As Integer = 0

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        litMenu.Text = PopulateChildren(Me.InsitePage.root_id)
    End Sub

    Protected Function PopulateChildren(ByVal nPgId As Integer) As String
        Dim sHTML As String = ""

        If nCount <= 2 Then
            Dim oCommand As SqlCommand
            Dim oDataReader As SqlDataReader

            oConn.Open()

            oCommand = New SqlCommand

            If Me.IsUserLoggedIn Then
                oCommand.CommandText = "select count(page_id) as count from pages_published where parent_id = @root_id and is_system = 0 and is_hidden = 0"
            Else
                oCommand.CommandText = "select count(page_id) as count from pages_working where parent_id = @root_id and is_system = 0 and is_hidden = 0"
            End If

            oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            oCommand.Parameters.Add("@root_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = nPgId
            oCommand.Connection = oConn
            oDataReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader()

            Dim nInt As Integer = 0

            While oDataReader.Read()
                nInt = oDataReader("count")
            End While

            oConn.Close()

            If nInt > 0 Then
                If nCount = 0 Then
                    sHTML = "<ul id=""myid2"" class=""dropdown"" data-role=""listview"" data-inset=""true"">"
                Else
                    sHTML = "<ul>"
                End If

                If nPgId = Me.InsitePage.root_id Then 'if it is the home page (root)
                    Dim oRootPage As InsitePage = New InsitePage(nPgId, Nothing)
                    sHTML += "<li><a href=""" & oRootPage.file_name & """ title=""" & Replace(oRootPage.title, """", "\""") & """>" & oRootPage.title & "</a></li>" 'Show Home Page link
                End If

                Dim listing As List(Of InsiteMenuItem)

                listing = New InsiteMenu().GetMenus(nPgId.ToString(), 0, nInt, "main")

                For Each root As InsiteMenuItem In listing
                    sHTML += "<li><a href=""" & root.file_name & """ title=""" & Replace(root.title, """", "\""") & """>" & root.title & "</a>"
                    If Not root.is_listing Then
                        nCount = nCount + 1
                        sHTML += PopulateChildren(root.page_id)
                    End If
                    sHTML += "</li>"
                Next

                sHTML += "</ul>"

                If sHTML = "<ul></ul>" Then
                    sHTML = ""
                End If
            End If
        End If

        nCount = nCount - 1

        Return sHTML
    End Function
</script>

<asp:Literal ID="litMenu" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Comment: Bring your data into memory in one shot and use that datastructure like List(of MenuPage) instead of all the database calls.

Comment: Any chance anyone could elaborate more or give an example? Really appreciate any and all help! :)

Comment: Basically, grab all the data from pages_published  and pages_working and put them in a Dictionary (by rootid?) or a List before you call PopulateChildren. Now you don't need to open a connection, fetch data and close the database for every level of your menu. Replace the database calls inside PopulateChildren with calls to your in memory collection using LINQ or other methods.